# Testing Salesforce CPQ

Tags: cpq, test-automation, steelbrick, selenium

I'm trying to create some meaningful tests for Salesforce CPQ. I'm trying to create Apex test classes and also UI tests with Selenium.

The problem with the apex tests is that a lot of the important functionality in CPQ relies on the Steelbrick API and is UI based.

The problem with Selenium (and other automated testing tools) is that CPQ uses the Shadow DOM which makes it very difficult to create the tests.

Has anyone been able to create meaningful tests around CPQ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This Salesforce developer blog post about "[Automating Salesforce CPQ Testing](https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/2019/05/automating-salesforce-cpq-testing.html)" provides useful recommendations, which may help anyone still looking for answers to this question.